# How to sort files entries correctly using Java and regex

Tags: java, regex, sorting, text, java-io

I have a text file "unsorted.txt" input containing the following entries:

```
37060635563
37067264426
37061457700
37067116332
37068672376
37068669157
```

I would like Java to sort out and format these number in output file "sorted.txt" in the following manner.

```
+370 606 35563
+370 614 57700
+370 686 69157
+370 686 72376
+370 671 16332
+370 672 64426
```

I have made sort Java code but it only produces one entry and i cannot find why?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
        
public class PhoneSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        final String regex = "(\\\\d{3})(\\\\d{3})(\\\\d*)";
        final String subst = "+$1 $2 $3";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        
        File us = new File("unsorted.txt");
        File st = new File("sorted.txt");
        String result = "";
        
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(us)){
                 while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(st)) {
                          writer.write(pattern.matcher(sc.nextLine()).replaceAll(subst)); 
                         } catch(IOException e){}
                    }
                }
        catch (IOException e){}   
    }
}
```

Comment: Never just consume errors, instead, print it to the console so you can see why it fails `catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}`, Also, you either need to close the file writer after each write, or you need to declare your file writer outside of your while loop rather than trying to create a new one every time.

Comment: What entries with `686` is appearing before `671`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a working example with the desired result**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String regex = "(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d*)";
    final String subst = "+$1 $2 $3";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);

    File us = new File("unsorted.txt");
    File st = new File("sorted.txt");

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(us));
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(st))) {
        reader.lines().sorted()
                .map(r -> pattern.matcher(r).replaceAll(subst))
                .forEach(res -> {
                    try {
                        writer.write(res);
                        writer.newLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know why your code only runs once then you need to do some debugging and you need to print out any caught exceptions to the console so you can see why your code fails `catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}`. Never just consume errors unless you know exactly what you are doing and what will happen if something breaks.

Now we have one of two issues, the first is that your code is failing and if so then the error that is being printed will show an issue with your file writer, which will likely mean that you need to close the file writer after each write, however that creates a different issue (see below).

However, the more likely issue is that you are making a new FileWriter each time and overriding your previous file. To solve this you need to declare your file writer outside of your while loop rather than trying to create a new one every time.

The following should work, note how we now print the error to the console, and how we only create the FileWriter once:

```
    //We can also add the true flag to append data to the file writer
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(us);
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(st, true);){            
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            writer.write(pattern.matcher(sc.nextLine()).replaceAll(subst)); 
        }
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @user15358848 I have updated my answer, I think you hit the nail on the head.

Comment: you have incorrect work with filewriter if an exception occurs during recording, the file will remain open, it must be declared in try-with-resources or manual closed in finally block

Comment: Dear @sorifiend you still haven't fixed the code for closing a file which is considered a  bad example use java.io, please fix.

Comment: `FileWriter` is also a resource which should be closed. Why is it not inside first section of try-with-resources along with Scanner so it would be closed automatically? For now `writer.close();` is inside `try` section so if some exception will be thrown before that line it will prevent calling `writer.close();`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this answer assuming you want the output to be,

```
+370 606 35563
+370 614 57700
+370 671 16332
+370 672 64426
+370 686 69157
+370 686 72376
```

My approach does not using Regex and it reads the file into memory.

1. Read all the lines from the file into a `List`.
2. Sort the above list as per the requirement. (Sort by the first three digits - if they are same, sort by the next three digits. Even if they are equal, sort by the rest of the digits).
3. Write the sorted list into a result file.

```
Path path = Paths.get("<fill_the_path>/unsorted.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path); 
List<String> sortedList = sort(lines);    

Files.write(Paths.get("<fill_the_path>/sorted.txt"),
            format(sortedList),
            StandardOpenOption.CREATE);



private List<String> sort(List<String> lines) {
    Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing((String s) -> Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, 3)))
            .thenComparing(s -> Integer.valueOf(s.substring(3, 6)))
            .thenComparing(s -> Integer.valueOf(s.substring(6)));
    return lines.stream()
            .sorted(comparator)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}


private List<String> format(List<String> lines) {
    return lines.stream()
            .map(this::formatLine)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private String formatLine(String line) {
    return "+" +
            line.substring(0, 3) + " " +
            line.substring(3, 6) + " " +
            line.substring(6);
}
```

Note: You can convert each line to a `Long` and use `Comparator.comparingLong` as well (if the value would fit into a `long`).

```
return lines.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Long::valueOf))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hello, probably I am wrong but it would be possible sort the numbers as strings and after format them to the three substrings? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @dariosicily this is how it is done and it gives the expected result  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67042184/how-to-sort-files-entries-correctly-using-java-and-regex/#answer-67042336

Comment: @dariosicilyin this case, when two texts of the same size can be sorted as text, but generally it is wrong to sort numbers as a string because the lines will be sorted character by character, therefore 11 will be considered more than 101